# How to put menu icon next to Table of Contents

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I put the little icon next to table of contents? Code is below.

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3 class="toggle-transparent tof">TABLE OF CONTENTS</h3>
        <img src="assets/images/menu.png" alt="">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Bootstrap floats class="pull-left"

 <div class="col-md-4">
    <h3 class="toggle-transparent tof pull-left">TABLE OF CONTENTS</h3>
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-
 alt-512.png" alt="" height="30px" width="30px" class="pull-left">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not dead-set on a specific icon, glyphicons are easiest. Just put it in a span right after to your text (with a space if needed):

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
   <h3 class="toggle-transparent tof">TABLE OF CONTENTS 
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>
   </h3>
 </div>
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/1T7zTW6E2l

Also, `glyphicon-list-alt` might be an alternate icon.

Comment: And if you **are** dead-set on your icon, still put it in span within the h1, but then you have to mess with height, margin, etc, as per: http://www.bootply.com/pnJsZU5vxb